# How to upload multiple files in database using laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, file-upload

I am new to laravel. I am trying to upload multiple files in form, but when I try to insert data, it is showing an error. I need to save the filenames into the database.Whenever I am trying to save form, it is showing an error as the file cannot be null.

What I have tried is:

twig:

```
 <form method="POST" action="/listingSave" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="sellingFormSave" id="sellingFormSave">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}"/>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{product.id}}"/>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-12 condition_radio">
                                                <div class="wrapper">
                                                    <span>Condition of the Trucks</span>
                                                    <div class="toggle_radio">
                                                        <input type="radio" class="toggle_option" id="as_is" value="as_is" name="condition" {{product.condition == 'as_is' ? 'checked':''}} {{product != '' ? 'disabled' : ''}}>
                                                        <input type="radio" class="toggle_option" id="dot_term" value="dot" name="condition" {{product.condition == 'dot' ? 'checked':''}} {{product != '' ? 'disabled' : ''}}>
                                                        <input type="radio" class="toggle_option" id="trade_term" value="trade" name="condition" {{product.condition == 'trade' ? 'checked':''}} {{product != '' ? 'disabled' : ''}}>
                                                        <label for="as_is"><p>As Is - Where Is</p></label>
                                                        <label for="dot_term"><p>DOT Term</p></label>
                                                        <label for="trade_term"><p>Trade Term</p></label>
                                                        <div class="toggle_option_slider">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                                <div class="field__input-wrapper">
                                                    <input type="text" class="field__input" placeholder="Name *" name="name" value="{{product.name}}" {{product != '' ? 'disabled' : 'required'}}>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row sell_form">
                                            <div class="col-12 section_title-js">
                                                <h3>Location of the Trucks</h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                <div class="field__input-wrapper">
                                                    <input type="text" class="field__input" placeholder="City *" name="city" value="{{product.city}}" {{product != '' ? 'disabled' : 'required'}}>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                <div class="field__input-wrapper">
                                                    {{ form.fields.state.setAttributes({ 'required' : 'required' }).input|raw }}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                <div class="field__input-wrapper">
                                                    <input type="text" class="field__input" placeholder="Zip *" name="zipcode" value="{{product.zipcode}}" {{product != '' ? 'disabled' : 'required'}}>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        {% if product == '' %}
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-12 section_title-js">
                                                <h3></h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                                <input id="demo" type="file" name="files" accept=".jpg, .png, image/jpeg, image/png" multiple>
                                                <!-- <input type="hidden" name="image[]" accept=".jpg, .png, image/jpeg, image/png" multiple> -->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        <div class="row">                                       
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-12">
                                                <div class="field__input-wrapper">
                                                    <input type="radio" name="quantity_type" value="single" {{product != '' ? 'disabled' : 'required'}} {{product.quantity_type == 'single' ? 'checked' : ''}}> Single
                                                    <input type="radio" name="quantity_type" value="fleet" {{product != '' ? 'disabled' : 'required'}} {{product.quantity_type == 'fleet' ? 'checked' : ''}}> Fleet
                                                </div><br>
                                                <!-- <div class="field__input-wrapper">
                                                    <input type="text" class="field__input" placeholder="Quantity *" name="quantity_on_hand" 
                                                           value="{{product.quantity_on_hand}}" {{product != '' ? 'readonly' : 'required'}}>
                                                </div><br>
                                                <div class="field__input-wrapper">
                                                    <input type="text" class="field__input" placeholder="Price($)" name="price" 
                                                           value="{{product.price}}" {{product != '' ? 'readonly' : ''}}>
                                                </div> -->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <div class="row">   
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-12">
                                                <table class="table mileageTable">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>Mileage</th>
                                                            <th>Price</th>
                                                            <th>Count</th>
                                                            {% if product != '' %}
                                                            <th>Sold</th>
                                                            {% endif %}
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        {% for mile in miles %}
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <input type="hidden" name="mileage_gap_id[]" value="{{mile.id}}">
                                                                {{mile.name}}
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <input class="price" name="mileage_price[{{mile.id}}]" 
                                                                       value="{{product.mileage_gaps.where('mileage_gap_id',mile.id).first() ? product.mileage_gaps.where('mileage_gap_id',mile.id).first().price : ''}}"
                                                                      >                                                         </td>   
                                                            <td>
                                                                <input class="number_of_products" name="number_of_products[{{mile.id}}]" 
                                                                       value="{{product.mileage_gaps.where('mileage_gap_id',mile.id).first() ? product.mileage_gaps.where('mileage_gap_id',mile.id).first().number_of_products : ''}}"
                                                                       >
                                                            </td>   
                                                            {% if product != '' %}      
                                                            <td>
                                                                <input class="number_of_products_sold" name="number_of_products_sold[{{mile.id}}]" 
                                                                       value="{{product.mileage_gaps.where('mileage_gap_id',mile.id).first() ? product.mileage_gaps.where('mileage_gap_id',mile.id).first().number_of_products_sold : ''}}"
                                                                       type="number">
                                                            </td>               
                                                            {% endif %}                             
                                                        </tr>
                                                        {% endfor %}
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>  
                                            
                                        </div>
                                        {% if product != '' %}
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                <span>Status</span>
                                                <select class="form-control" name="status">
                                                    <option value="open" {{product.status == 'open' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Open</option>
                                                    <option value="pending" {{product.status == 'pending' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Pending</option>
                                                    <option value="sold" {{product.status == 'sold' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Sold</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        {% endif %}

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-12 section_title-js">
                                                <h3></h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                <div class="field__input-wrapper">
                                                    <input type="text" class="field__input" placeholder="Engine Type" name="engine_type" value="{{product.engine_type}}" {{product != '' ? 'disabled' : ''}}>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                <div class="field__input-wrapper">
                                                    <input type="text" class="field__input" placeholder="Horsepower" name="horsepower" value="{{product.horsepower}}" {{product != '' ? 'disabled' : ''}}>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                <div class="field__input-wrapper">
                                                    <select name="transmission" class="field__input" data-field="transmission" data-field_name="transmission" 
                                                            data-provides="anomaly.field_type.transmission" id="transmission" {{product != '' ? 'disabled' : ''}}>
                                                        <option value="">Type of Transmission</option>
                                                        <option value="Automated" {{product.transmission == 'Automated' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Automated</option>
                                                        <option value="Automatic" {{product.transmission == 'Automatic' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Automatic</option>
                                                        <option value="Manual" {{product.transmission == 'Manual' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Manual</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                <div class="field__input-wrapper">
                                                    <input type="text" class="field__input" placeholder="Transmission Speed" name="transmission_speed" value="{{product.transmission_speed}}" {{product != '' ? 'disabled' : ''}}>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                <div class="field__input-wrapper">
                                                    <input type="text" class="field__input" placeholder="Transmission Model" name="transmission_model" value="{{product.transmission_model}}" {{product != '' ? 'disabled' : ''}}>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                <div class="field__input-wrapper">
                                                    <select name="bunks" class="field__input" data-field="bunks" 
                                                            data-field_name="bunks" id="bunks" {{product != '' ? 'disabled' : ''}}>
                                                        <option value=""># of Bunks</option>
                                                        <option value="1" {{product.bunks == '1' ? 'selected' : ''}}>1</option>
                                                        <option value="2" {{product.bunks == '2' ? 'selected' : ''}}>2</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                                <div class="field__input-wrapper">
                                                    <textarea placeholder="Description of the Trucks" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" rows="3" {{product != '' ? 'disabled' : ''}}>{{product.description}}</textarea>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-12 section_title-js">
                                                <h3></h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                                <div class="field__input-wrapper field_input__confirm">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" id="confirm" name="confirm[]" value="yes" {{product.confirm != '' ? 'checked' : ''}} {{product != '' ? 'disabled' : 'required'}}>
                                                    <label for="confirm"> I certify that the above facts are true to the best of my knowledge and belief.</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn">
                                            Save
                                        </button>
                                        <a href="/truckian-dashboard" class="_btn dash_btn">Back to Dashboard</a>

                                    </form>
```

Controller:

```
public function listingSave(Request $request) {
    
    $condition=$request->input('condition');
    echo $condition;
    $p_name=$request->input('name');
    $city=$request->input('city');
    $zipcode=$request->input('zipcode');  
    $qtype=$request->input('quantity_type');
    $status=$request->input('status');
    $engine_type=$request->input('engine_type');
    $horsepower=$request->input('horsepower');
    $transmission=$request->input('transmission');
    $transmission_model=$request->input('transmission_model');
    $transmission_speed=$request->input('transmission_speed');
    $description=$request->input('description');
     $confirm=$request->input('confirm[]');
      $bunks=$request->input('bunks');
   $files=$request->input('files');
    DB::insert('insert into default_truckian_products(product_name,p_condition,city,zipcode,files,quantity_type,status,engine_type,horse_power,transmission, transmission_speed,transmission_model, bunks,description,confirm) values (?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [$p_name,$condition,$city,$zipcode,$files,$qtype,$status,$engine_type,$horsepower,$transmission,$transmission_speed,$transmission_model,$bunks,$description,$confirm]);
}
```

When to try to execute this code , it is showing error like this:

[image: Output]

How to insert file names and files to database.

Comment: Your variable for files is __$file=$request->input('files');__ but in your query you are using $files (that has no value, so it is null). You must modify your asignment to __$files=$request->input('files');__

Comment: @nacho . Not working

Comment: Check laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-uploads

You should use $request->file('files') to access the uploaded files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <input id="demo" type="file" name="files[]" accept=".jpg, .png, image/jpeg, image/png" multiple>

        if($request->hasfile('files'))
         {
            foreach($request->file('files') as $file)
            {
                $name = time().'.'.$file->extension();
                $file->move(public_path().'/files/', $name);  
                $data[] = $name;  
            }
         }
```

try this. it is worked for me.